# Extract rows from pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the pandas dataframe "data", and want to keep only the rows where the sum
of "numb_people" per category "class" is at least 2.

This, however, throws an index error (the indices do not match anymore):

```
data = data[data.groupby('class').sum()['numb_people'] > 2]
```

How can I do this in a similarly simple manner?

Comment: Please [provide a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `to_clipboard`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-the-dataframe-with-to-clipboard/52413247#52413247)

Comment: `data[data.groupby('class').numb_people.transform('sum') > 2]`

Comment: If I do data = data[data.groupby('class').numb_people.transform('sum') > 2], is this thresholding the data by this criterion such that only classes with sum > 2 are left, or is this new data variable actually containing sums (which it should not)?

Comment: `groupby` expressions in pandas have the [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#filtration) method that might make this code a little more elegant than using the `transform` method. It's pandas' closest equivalent to a SQL-like HAVING statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rafaelc said in comment:

```
idx = data.groupby('class').numb_people.transform('sum') > 2
print(data[idx])
```